# When I wrote npm install in terminal,npm: command not found is said

Tags: node.js

When I wrote `npm install` in terminal,npm: command not found is said.
I wanna use a command `npm install http-server`,and run a server.
So,I installed nodebrew,it was successful.
But when I put `npm install`,terminal said

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Furthermore,I wrote `npm install http-server`,terminal said

```
/Users/XXX
└─┬ http-server@0.10.0 
  ├── colors@1.0.3 
  ├── corser@2.0.1 
  ├─┬ ecstatic@2.2.1 
  │ ├── he@1.1.1 
  │ ├── mime@1.3.6 
  │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
  │ └── url-join@2.0.2 
  ├─┬ http-proxy@1.16.2 
  │ ├── eventemitter3@1.2.0 
  │ └── requires-port@1.0.0 
  ├── opener@1.4.3 
  ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1 
  │ ├── minimist@0.0.10 
  │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3 
  ├─┬ portfinder@1.0.13 
  │ ├── async@1.5.2 
  │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.8 
  │ │ └── ms@2.0.0 
  │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
  │   └── minimist@0.0.8 
  └─┬ union@0.4.6 
    └── qs@2.3.3 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/XXX/package.json'
npm WARN XXX No description
npm WARN XXX No repository field.
npm WARN XXX No README data
npm WARN XXX No license field.
```

I think,npm command cannot be installed, so I cannot use it.
But,I cannot understand how to fix this.
What should I do to fix this?
When I wrote `npm init` in Users/XXX,traceback said

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "init"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /Users/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/package.json' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "init"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.286252312
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.286252312'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.286252312'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.286252312' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: have you installed node?

Comment: do you have package.json in /Users/XXX/ ?

Comment: @suraj Yes,Node installer said 
Node.js was installed at

   /usr/local/bin/node

npm was installed at

   /usr/local/bin/npm

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

Comment: @ZeroCho I think so... Node installer said Node.js was installed at /usr/local/bin/node npm was installed at /usr/local/bin/npm Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

Comment: what does `echo $PATH` give?

Comment: @suraj It said, /Users/xxx/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/Users/xxx/.pyenv/shims:/Users/xxx/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/xxx/.nodebrew/current/bin

Comment: The error log says `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/XXX/package.json'`. Did you call `npm init` in `/Users/XXX`?

Comment: @ZeroCho No,I wrote npm init in /Users/XXX.But error happens,so I added it to my question.

Comment: you get command not found for `npm init`?

Comment: you might want to check https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions